# Setting Mercurial username

Tags: mercurial

So I'm trying to use Mercurial but it wants me to set up a username.

I found various solutions to this online but they don't seem to work, I tried creating a file called mercurial.ini in my home folder and putting:

```
[ui]
username = My Name <My email is in here">
```

The showconfig command returns:

```
C:\Users\John\Mercurial>hg showconfig ui --debug
read config from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\hgrc.d\Mercurial.rc
read config from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\hgrc.d\MergeTools.rc
read config from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\hgrc.d\Paths.rc
read config from: C:\Users\John\mercurial.ini
read config from: C:\Users\John\.hgrc
read config from: C:\Users\John\mercurial.ini
read config from: C:\Users\John\.hgrc
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `type C:\Users\John\mercurial.ini`, pls ???

Comment: Well it keeps throwing up the error that I haven't created a username. And where did you want me to type that Badger?

Comment: Type Badger's command on, you know, the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have `[ui]` and `username` on separate lines (it wasn't clear you did in your question until I edited it) the only causes I can think of are:

- file permissions
- correct directory
- correct file type
- correct line endings

It needs to be a text file (not rtf or word).  It needs to be readable by you.  It needs to be in `C:\Users\John\`.

As a test try this:

`hg showconfig --debug`

(no `ui` in that).  Does it give any output at all?

Comment: Ok, so I got it to work. Making a .txt file called mercurial.ini didn't work, but copying the hgrc file from the .hg folder from one of my projects and renaming it did.
So I suppose the problem was that it was the wrong type of file, I guess? Anyway, thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: My quess is the file was actually called "Mercurial.ini.txt", which is what Notepad wants to create, and then windows hides the extension from you to be "helpful".  Consider selecting the answer (or just deleting your question) if you're not still looking for answers so as to save future answerers some time.

Comment: What the original poster did should have worked, since it worked for me, so possible causes shown here are worth looking at.  I created a .ini file through Explorer in Win 7 by right clicking in my home directory, selecting New -> Text File, naming it Mercurial with a capital 'M', then editing the file suffix to .ini.  You can then edit with Notepad and put your username entry in there.  Helped me with my problem trying to use Mercurial in Eclipse.